Understanding reSize() and add() for Vector class
Hi I am struggling with a java problem.
I am trying to understand how to assign value x to new elements added to a vector where the existing elements would remain unchanged, e.g. if it was resized from 3 to 5 then the 4th and 5th would have value x.
Additionally, in the next class I want to add another vector _v to the current vector. If this is bigger than the length of the current vector that reSize(int _size) is called. How do I write this?
public class Vector {
    private double[] doubElements;

    public Vector(double[] _elements) {
        this.doubElements = _elements;
        
    }

public int getVectorSize() {
    
    return doubElements.length;
}

public Vector reSize(int _size) {
    if (_size == (doubElements.length - 1) || _size <= 0){
        return null;
    } else if (_size < (doubElements.length - 1)) {
        return new Vector(new double[]{doubElements[_size]});
    } else {
        return new Vector(new double[]{doubElements.add(-1.0)});
    }
    
}

public Vector add(Vector _v) {
    Vector.this.add(_v);
    if (getVectorSize(doubElements.length)) {
        reSize()...
        return null;
    }
}



You perhaps should look at Arrays.copyOf(...) to find how to copy an array.

There are several problems here. Look at this line in the constructor: this.doubElements = _elements;.  In Java, an array is a reference type, i.e., an Object. So, doubElements in a Vector Object becomes an alias for the array used in the constructor. If you want doubElements to be independent of the array, you need to copy the elements.  You could use Arrays.copyOf. But, since you are a beginner, consider coding your own copy method.

Since an array is not resizable, neither will your Vector be. If you want a Vector to be resizable, you should have another instance variable: int size; which represents how many elements of doubElements are actually used.

new Vector(new double[]{doubElements[_size]}); might not  do what you think it  does. It will create a new Vector with exactly one element. That element will be the element of doubElements indexed by _size.  Also, new Vector(new double[]{doubElements.add(-1.0)}) unless you have an add method that accepts a double argument. The code you show has an add method that accepts a Vector, which is neither a double nor can be converted to a double.
